# How to cancel previous email verifications when django email verification link is sent

Tags: django

After the user changes their email, I get the email activation status wrong and logout, but the user can log back in using the verification from their previous email. To prevent this, I want to cancel all email activation codes that the user previously received when they changed their email. how can I do this?

```
def emailchange(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usermail = ProfileAuthSettings(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        user = MyUser.objects.filter(username = request.user.username).first()
        if usermail.is_valid():
            cleaneddata = usermail.cleaned_data.get('email')
            print('emial',user.email ,cleaneddata)
            if not user.email == cleaneddata:
                user.email = cleaneddata
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                asyncio.run(ActiveEmail(request,user))               
                messages.success(request,'email change')
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                return redirect('login2')
    else:
        return redirect('404')

@sync_to_async
def ActiveEmail(request,creatuser):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    mail_subject = "accountactivate"
    message = render_to_string('activate_account.html',{
        'user':creatuser,
        'domain': current_site.domain,
        'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(creatuser.pk)),
        'token': account_activation_token.make_token(creatuser),

    })
    send_mail(mail_subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [creatuser.email])
```

Model

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    
    avatar = models.ImageField(("Avatar"), upload_to='avatar/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank=True,null=True)
    banner = models.ImageField(("Banner"), upload_to='banner/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank=True,null=True)
    rank = models.ManyToManyField(Rank, verbose_name=("Rankı"),blank=True,null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(("birthday"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,blank=True,null=True)
    location = models.CharField(("location"), max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)
    website = models.CharField(("Website"), max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    about = models.TextField(("about"),blank=True,null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField("post_app.post", verbose_name=("Beğendiğim postlar"),related_name="mylikes")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(("email"),default=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'MyUser'
        verbose_name_plural = 'MyUsers'
    def user_profile_detail_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'profile_detail',
            kwargs={
                'username': self.username
            }
        )
    

from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
import six
class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return(
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )
account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
password_reset_token = TokenGenerator()
```

Comment: Please share the related models.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I updated my post if this is what you mean by models